# Portfolio optimization Monte Carlo Simulation in python. Summation constraint problem

Tags: optimization, simulation, montecarlo, portfolio

I have a problem with the "sum to one" constraint in my monte carlo simulation. I am simulating 1 million different weights to create different portfolios, but the problem is how I can make the simulation understand that the sum of the random variables only can sum to one. The one I have now will work, but the problem is that if I have too many assets, for example 100 assets, every weight will be divided by the sum of the weights to make it sum to one. This means that I will never get the case that one weight is for example 0.7 one weight is 0.3 and the rest is zero. Now every weight will be around 0.02 - 0.07 In other words the extremes will never happen which makes my distribution wrong.

Does anybody know how to make a constraint that lets the weights take absolutely every single combination as long as I simulate enough times? The red circles are my constraint now.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as images.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is nearly impossible to have 0 as the result of 98 randomizations. If you want to get the extremes in some cases, then just simply randomize a number of values, k (for example 2) instead of the total number n (for example 100) and append as many zeroes as needed.

The basic question is: how much chance is that from 100 random values whose sum will be 1 you have 98 zeroes. The chance is so small that it likely never happens. So, you will need to artificially add those cases if they may be important.

EDIT

In order to have a chance of higher values and obtain fully random values, you can implement the following algorithm:

```
sum <- 0
step <- 1
while (step < limit) do
    value <- random_between(0, 1 - sum)
    sum <- sum + value
    random_values[step - 1] <- value
    step <- step + 1
end while
random_values[step - 1] <- 1 - sum
```

This will significantly increase the chance of having a larger value, because you do not restrict your current randomization to an even distribution. However, the problem in this case is that this scenario makes it highly unlikely that an even distribution will occur as the result. So, let's name your current way of randomizing as `even_distribution` and the algorithm I have given above `uneven_distribution`. Before you generate your randoms, compute a random between 0 and 1. If it's <= 0.5, then call `even_distribution`. Otherwise call `uneven_distribution`. This will make your chance of having an even distribution as likely as having an uneven distribution.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i agree on the probability there. I didn't expect it to be 98 zeros, but it will never give me a weight in any asset of for example 0,5 and the rest spread out since my constraint "smooth" it out. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: What I means is that if the random number generated is 0.5 or 0.7 or 0.2 or whatever, it will be divided by the sum, which leads to a very low weight. So I will never be able to get for example 0.5 in an asset.

Comment: @Prebish you can define a value to be 0.5 and randomize 99 other values, dividing them with 100 / (1 - 0.5) = 200.

Comment: Okay, I like that thought. There is still a problem with the last 99 shares tho. I will never get those cases where we have 0.4, 0.2, 0.1 and the rest spread on the last 97 weights?. If We define a value to be 0.5 the 99 other values will be very very low... I just want it to be completely random what the weights are. Every asset should be able to take high and low weights. In the case above only one weight will have a pretty high value.. ?

Comment: @Prebish I have provided an idea to equalize the chance of having an even distribution and uneven distribution. I have edited my answer to add an algorithm and a description.

Comment: Aprad. Looks very nice. I cant seem to be able to implement it. Is this created in python? And i dont really understand a few variables there that are not defined like random_between or limit :)

Comment: @Prebish this is pseudo-code. It's not actual code. I would write actual code if I was fluent in Python, but due to the fact that I have never worked with Python except answering a few questions here on SO, I do not delve into writing code in Python at this point. But since I do understand the problem that you face and I know how it should be solved conceptionally, I have given the logic you may want to use while you implement the solution. But, I'm afraid that I cannot help you with the proper Python function or library.

Comment: @Prebish `limit` is the number of values you want to randomize. `random_values` is the collection/array you will have as an output.

Comment: @Prebish we have an offset in the indexation on purpose because the very last item will not be randomized due to the fact that it's forced to have such a value that the sum of the elements will yield 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using approach

```
weights = np.random.random(num_assets)
weights /= np.sum(weights)
```

is questionable in itself, you don't know underlying distribution, marginal probabilities etc.

> Now every weight will be around 0.02 - 0.07 In other words the extremes will never happen which makes my distribution wrong.

You could get it all the way you want to be if you change underlying distribution for the [Dirichlet one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). Then you'll know marginal distributions, means, etc. And feature of Sum<sub>i</sub>(X<sub>i</sub>)=1 you'll automatically, as property of the distribution.

Along the lines (untested!)

```
alpha = num_assets*[1.0]
weights = np.random.dirichlet(alpha)
```

you'll get random vector with Sum<sub>i</sub>(weights<sub>i</sub>)=1 and E[weights<sub>i</sub>] = 1/num_assets.

> I will never get the case that one weight is for example 0.7 one weight is 0.3 and the rest is zero.

That is very easy to do with Dirichlet

Along the lines (untested again!)

```
alpha = [0,0,0, ..., 0.3, 0, 0, ..., 0.7, ... 0, 0, 0] # with length=num_assets
weights = np.random.dirichlet(alpha)
```

you should get random values with means 0.3 and 0.7 and zeroes elsewhere. You could get (almost) exactly 0.3 and 0.7 by decreasing variance